# Define two login_url with login_required in django

Tags: django

In my app, I have two different login pages according the user that need to log in. So I cannot use `settings.LOGIN_URL`.

I am also using class-based views, so I have to use `method_decorator(login_required)`.

At this moment, I have a class decorator (I am using Python 2.7) that does pretty much all what I want, except for the `login_url`. Code is a snippet and hand-typed, so it may have typo.

```
login_required_m = method_decorator(login_required)
def requires_role1(view):
  def requires_m(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      # I need to process request.user
      if (not ok):
        return redirect(urlresolvers.reverse('some_name'))
      else:
        f = login_required_m(func)
        return f(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
  view.get = requires_m(view.get)
  view.post = requires_m(view.post)
  return view
```

The line that really concerns me is:

```
`f = login_required_m(func)`
```

On a function based view, I would have been able to define:

```
`f = login_required(func, login_url='some_reverse_path')`
```

but with `method_decorator(login_required)`, I am no longer able to pass `login_url` as a parameter. Remember, I need to be able to do so because I have two different login urls. They provide totally different sets of usernames and passwords (same username can be in both set with different passwords and associated to different people).

Any help in what I should do to accomplish this would be much appreciated.

*EDIT*

Accorded to accepted answer, here is the solution I adopted:

```
def login_required_partial(func):
  return partial(login_required, login_url=urlresolvers.reverse('role1_login'))

login_required_m = method_decorator(login_required_partial)
```

and left the rest of the code unchanged. And it all seems to work well when there are no parameters passed by `ulr(r'path/(?P<param1>.*)', CBV.as_view(), name='path_name')`.

Anyone with a good way to fix this now?

Comment: Have you considered decorating of an url pattern at urls.py?

Comment: I have, but have issues because of the `reverse('url_name')` being not defined yet at that time. Importing issues I think.

Comment: reverse_lazy is available to use in urls.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decorate the CBV view function:

```
# urls.py

from myproj.myapp import views

myview = login_required(views.MyView.as_view(), login_url=None)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('^$', myview),
)
```

Or you can create some sort of a mixin:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from functools import partial

class LoginRequiredMixin(object):
    """
    A mixin used for views that can only be accessed by authenticated users.
    """

    login_url = None

    def _login_required(self):
        return partial(login_required, login_url=self.login_url)

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            klass = LoginRequiredMixin
            return super(klass, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

        return partial(inner, login_url=self.login_url)(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

And use it like so:

```
 # View class
 class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
     login_url = lazy_reverse('foo')

     pass

 # Or a view function in urls.py
 myview = views.MyView.as_view(login_url=reverse('foo'))
```

Comment: For the first part of the answer (withing `urls.py`), it's not possible because the link is resolved from a `url_name` and is not completely defined at that moment. I need to think about the mixin because I never used it. Need to read about `partial()`.

Comment: Ok, i didn't read about partial but went straight testing it and it seems to work. I have not opted with the mixin class, but instead just added the intermediary `def` straight in my code.

Comment: Unfortunately, the way I changed my code did not allow me to receive params from `url()`. Any idea how i could do that?

Comment: Great that it works! I haven't tested this and it think it was because the method decorator gets constructed before the class attribute is assigned when the view function gets constructed. I've updated it with something that should allow `login_url` to be specified when the view function is being constructed.

Comment: The problem is the method_decorator modifies the method enough that it stops working with parameters from URLconf. I think it's not production prime in this state. I refactored my project to take care of everything within the dispatch(). I'll accept your answer although it did not totally gave me a working environment. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
class MyView(View):

  @method_decorator(lambda x: login_required(x, login_url=reverse_lazy('role1_login')))
  def post(self, request):
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

It looks like this is working for me.